# Any reason why this LINQ to SQL update query is not working . . 

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Somehow this update code is not working:

Here is my Controller code:

```
    private UserRepository repo = new UserRepository();

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, UserInfo user_)
    {
        try
        {
            repo.UpdateUser(user_);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Here is the repo code that is used above (UserRepository)

```
    private UsersDataContext db = new UsersDataContext();

    public void UpdateUser(UserInfo user_)
    {
        UserInfo origUser = GetUser(user_.Id);
        origUser.First = user_.First;
        origUser.Last = user_.Last;
        origUser.City = user_.City;
        origUser.Country = user_.Country;
        origUser.State = user_.State;
        origUser.Street_Address = user_.Street_Address;

        db.SubmitChanges();
    }

    public UserInfo GetUser(int id_)
    {
        return db.UserInfos.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Id == id_);
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Note that when debugging everything is running fine (no exceptions) but when it redirects back to Index the data has not been updated when the changes from the update.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the exception it's catching?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"?  Is the action method not getting fired?  Is the database method not getting fired?  Are you setting breakpoints and verifying contents of user_ if they are?

Comment: i have updated the post with these answers

Comment: I like the comment from "womp". Usually a very bad idea to catch and swallow every kind of exception.

Comment: again,  I am NOT getting any exception . . the index page just doesn't seem to update

Comment: @me, is the data in user_ the stuff that you expect? Also does origUser.First (or any property) get updated while you debug? Also does it actually update the database and just not update the webpage?

Comment: Can you post the controller code for the Index page as well? Maybe you're passing cached data into the Model for the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just changed the userrepository to the following:

```
private UsersDataContext db = new UsersDataContext();

public void UpdateUser(UserInfo user_)
{
    UserInfo origUser = db.UserInfos.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Id == id_);
    origUser.First = user_.First;
    origUser.Last = user_.Last;
    origUser.City = user_.City;
    origUser.Country = user_.Country;
    origUser.State = user_.State;
    origUser.Street_Address = user_.Street_Address;

    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

so all i did was move the GetUser() method inline and it worked.

It might have been a red herring and it was just a caching issue . .

Comment: glad you've found it, I don't understand why this would work and your previous code wouldn't. All you did was remove the function wrapping that getter...

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention how you've defined UserInfo, is it a struct or a class?

If it's a struct, returning it from GetUser will create a new object and thus you will not update the database object, only a local copy of it.

Moving the GetUser inline avoid this temp copy creation and that's likely why it's working.

afaik you could do something like

```
public void GetUser(int id_, out UserInfo user_)
{
    user_ = db.UserInfos.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Id == id_);
}
```

You would then call it like this

```
public void UpdateUser(UserInfo user_)
{
    UserInfo origUser;
    GetUser(user_.Id, out origUser);
    origUser.First = user_.First;
    origUser.Last = user_.Last;
    origUser.City = user_.City;
    origUser.Country = user_.Country;
    origUser.State = user_.State;
    origUser.Street_Address = user_.Street_Address;

    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you disabled Object Tracking?